# No IP forwarding in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, server, internet

I not familar with Linux or Ubuntu that much.
I recently installed an Ubuntu server 14.04.05 LTS on a *HP Proliant server*. My problem is that I can not get into the Internet with my *Windows 10 Client*. The server has access to the internet and the clients have access to the Ubuntu server, but not to the internet. IP forwarding is set to "1"

```
{{
auto lo em2 em1
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface em2 inet static
    address 192.168.178.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.178.0
    broadcast 192.168.178.255
    dns-nameserver 10.10.1.1 
    dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 
    dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4 
    gateway 192.168.178.1
    dns-domain vgg.net
    dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1
    dns-domain vgg.net localhost.localnet
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed

iface em1 inet static
    address 10.10.1.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.10.1.0
    broadcast 10.10.255.255
    dns-nameserver 10.10.1.1 
    dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 
    dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4 
    post-up iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em2 -j MASQUERADE
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
    dns-domain vgg.net localhost.localnet
}}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`. Does your iptables-restore overwrite your MASQUERADE rule?

Comment: Thanks, but I got it working now. Made a mistake in iptables and NAT.

Comment: @UdoB What changes you made .. can you please help?